# Android ExpandableListView SimpleCursorTreeAdapter starts up empty will crash

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-cursoradapter

I am writing an Android app (targets at Android ver 2.1 up).  I am using an `ExpandableListView` with a `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter`.  I find that it would crash follow this sequence:

1. The `ExpandableListView` starts up empty (i.e. no corresponding records in the database).
2. Record(s) are added.
3. Return to the screen with the `ExpandableListView`.  Now, group(s) are shown.
4. Click on the group to expand, the activity will be forced close.

After days of Internet searching and then painful tracing of my application's source and then Android's platform source, 
**it seems that the problem is:** when the Android platform initiates Ithe `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter`,
 it would store the list of children fields in private member `mChildFrom` once during instantiation and (strangely) **ON CONDITION THAT** if there is at least one group.  If there is no record (and therefore no group), the list of children fields are not stored.  When records are added subsequently and when expanding group to shown children rows, the `ExpandableListView` will crash because the private member `mChildFrom` is null.

**So, my get-around right now is:** only instantiate the `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` if there is relevant record in the database.  If not, retry the instantiation during `OnResume()`.

It would be helpful to me (or other poor guys having the same problem) if anybody has better reason for the crash, or has better solution.  (I incline to believe that it is a bug in the Android platform.)

Comment: Can you show the code of your activity.

Comment: @Flo, I really don't want to post the lengthy codes (there will be codes related to ExpandableListView, SimpleCursorTreeAdapter, database access and etc.)  If it turns out the problem is unique to me and others cannot recreate the problem, I will drill on my codes again.  My work around seems OK, but I really want to have a more elegant / straight forward solution.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611927/simplecursortreeadapter-and-cursorloader

Comment: I to have an issue that the app crashed when the group has 0 children

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Instantiate the adapter in onCreate() but pass null as cursor argument. In onResume() you then create new Cursor and pass it to the adapter using the [changeCursor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorTreeAdapter.html#changeCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29). By this you always get a new cursor whenever you change anything (add, delete, edit row) on you data model.

Comment: if my understanding is correct, the problem is not related to the cursor, but the instantiation of the adapter.  Once the adapter is instantiated when there is no relevant record, the member mChildFrom is not set up probably and the activity will crash.

Comment: Ah ok, I checked the SimpleCursorTreeAdapter source and see what your problem is and you're right, it has nothing to do with the cursor.

Comment: a second thought, passing a null cursor during instantiation of the adapter seems a recommended way as shown in the sample ExpandableList2 [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList2.html).  The logic flows will be different and maybe the problem is avoided.  To try that, I would need to study the queryHandler.  I may try that later and advise the result subsequently.

Comment: Normally you pass the cursor later as you should retrieve it on an own thread so the UI won't be blocked. AsyncTask are useful to do this.

Comment: No, passing a null cursor during instantiation does not work for 2.x versions.  Checking the Android source, SimpleCursorTreeAdapter is implemented quite differently among older and newer Android versions.  It is a nightmare if you want to support multiple versions with the same implementation.  I regret using the ExpandableListView.  My get-around breaks down too on the 4.x version, because I need to call startManagingCursor, which would cause problem in 4.x platform.